# problem: FFMPEG seeking with av_seek_frame using byte positions

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I am trying to get the av_seek_frame() function to go to a byte position I specify. I am implementing a frame accurate seeking mechanism for my application, and the way I see it, I will scan the entire video file, and store byte positions for each keyframe in a struct. I found out where to get the current byte position: AVPacket.pos.  I now test this position with `av_seek_frame` like this:

```
av_seek_frame( pFormatCtx, videoStream, 110285594, AVSEEK_FLAG_BYTE);
```

However, this does not seem to do the right thing, when I call `av_read_frame`, it just starts with frame 23. If I do not seek, it starts at frame 1.

Comment: Is the problem because you're trying to seek to a frame that's not a key frame?

Comment: Hi Dmazzoni, no I made sure the position was a Key Frame. I might add to it, that it is an h264 video.

Answer (score 13):

For those who are interested, I found the solution. After hours of googling and some simplistic form of reverse engineering, I found how to get and set the byte location of the open video.

To get the file position:
AVFormatContext.pb.pos

for example:

```
int64_t byteposition = pFormatCtx->pb->pos;
```

To set the file position:
url_seek(AVFormatContext.pb, Position, SEEK_SET);

for example:

```
url_seek(pFormatCtx->pb, 27909056, SEEK_SET);
```

Don't forget to flush the buffers if you change the location while playing. If you do this before you do av_read_frame for the first time, flushing is not necessary.

Kind Regards,
Nick Verlinden

Answer (score 7):

In recent versions of libav, url_seek has been made an internal function. One should now use the following function:

```
/**
* fseek() equivalent for AVIOContext.
* @return new position or AVERROR.
*/
int64_t avio_seek(AVIOContext *s, int64_t offset, int whence);
```