# Problem with ffmpeg function avformat_seek_file()

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavformat

I am trying to seek the given frame in the video using ffmpeg library. I knew that there is `av_seek_frame()` function but it was recommended to use `avformat_seek_file()`instead. Something similar mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261658/how-to-seek-in-ffmpeg-c-c).

I know that `avformat_seek_file()` can't always take you to exact frame you want, but this is ok for me. I just want to jump to the nearest keyframe. So i open the video, find videostream and calling it like this:

```
avformat_seek_file( formatContext, streamId, 0, frameNumber, frameNumber, AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME )
```

It always returns 0, so i understand it as correct finish. However, it doesn't work as it should to. I check byte position like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032929/problem-ffmpeg-seeking-with-av-seek-frame-using-byte-positions) before and after calling `avformat_seek_file()`. Actually it changes, but it changes always in the same way whenever i'm trying to put different target frame numbers! I mean that byteposition after this call is always same even with different `frameNumber` values. Obviously, i'm doing something wrong but i don't know what exactly. I don't know if it does matter but i'm using .h264 files for that. I tried different flags, different files, using timestamps instead of frames, flushing buffers before and after and so on but it doesn't work for me. I will be very grateful if someone could show me what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, see the code bellow (it works for me):

```
    ...
    checkPosition(input_files[file_index].ctx);
    ...

    void checkPosition(AVFormatContext *is) {
        int stream_index = av_find_default_stream_index(is);
        //Convert ts to frame
        tm = av_rescale(tm, is->streams[stream_index]->time_base.den, is->streams[stream_index]->time_base.num);
        tm /= 1000;

        //SEEK
        if (avformat_seek_file(is, stream_index, INT64_MIN, tm, INT64_MAX, 0) < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "ERROR av_seek_frame: %u\n", tm);
        } else {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "SUCCEEDED av_seek_frame: %u newPos:%d\n", tm, is->pb->pos);
            avcodec_flush_buffers(is->streams[stream_index]->codec);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, This is working for ffmpeg 0.11.1 and below versions. But, when I use above versions(ffmpeg 2.1 and above) I am getting problem means when we apply seek, some of mp3 songs are playing above duration also. Will u tell any solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

your problem may be related to the fact that your input is raw .h264. try using e.g. mp4box to mux it into a .mp4 file, then load the mp4 file with ffmpeg and try to seek to a keyframe again. e.g.:

```
mp4box -new -add my_file.h264 my_file.mp4
```